# Rails Api many to many how to send and handle json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rails-api

I created many to many association into my project and it looks like that:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :C, through: :B
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :carray
end

class B < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :A
 belongs_to :C
end

class C < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :A, through: :B
end
```

The extra thing is that I want to save number in every connection between A and C, so B table has additionally column number:integer. Table A and C has name column. My AController looks like that:

```
class RController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def create
    @a = A.new(a_params)
    @a.save
  end

  ...

  def a_params
    params.require(:a).permit([:name, carray_attributes: [:c_id, :number]])
  end
end
```

When I send json:

```
{
  "name" : "A name",
  "carray_attributes":
     [
       {
         "id_c": "3",
         "number": "23"
       },
       {
         "id_c": "3",
         "number": "15"
       }
     ]         
}
```

I get error UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'number' for C. Do you have any idea how to save number into table B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly create the join model if you need additional attributes besides just the foreign keys. For example:

```
# rails g model Employee name:string
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :positions
  has_many :companies, through: :positions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions
end

# rails g model Position name:string employee:belongs_to company:belongs_to
class Position < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end

# rails g model Company name:string
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :positions
  has_many :employees, through: :positions
end
```

Here `positions` is the join table. If we want to create a position with a name attribute while creating a company we need to pass two levels of nested attributes:

```
Employee.create(
  name: 'Bob',
  positions_attributes: [
    {
      name: 'CEO',
      company_attributes: {
        name: 'Acme Corp.'
      }
    } 
  ]
)
```

Comment: Ok, so if I want to enter the id of the (existing) company the employee should belong to, where should I put the company_id in json?

Comment: `{ "positions_attributes": { "name": "CEO", "company_id": 1 } }`

Comment: I have one more question. Maybe you know what should i put inside serializer if I want to show "name" of position. I mean I want to have in json { "company_id", "company_name", "position_name"} for every employee.  When i put has_many :companies through: :positions in serializer, I get only {"company_id", "company_name"} there is no "position_name" which is added to every connection in position table

Comment: Please create a separate question instead.